# Error building a ManageIQ container from git

Tags: docker, containers

I am trying to build a ManageIQ container from its source code
and I am seeing errors doing so..
I am using the following:

```
sudo docker build -t darga-container-28072016 .
```

and receiving the following error:

```
Step 11 : RUN curl -sSLko /etc/yum.repos.d/rhscl-rh-postgresql94-epel-7.repo https://copr-fe.cloud.fedoraproject.org/coprs/rhscl/rh-postgresql94/repo/epel-7/rhscl-rh-postgresql94-epel-7.repo && curl -sSLko /etc/yum.repos.d/ncarboni-pglogical-SCL-epel-7.repo https://copr.fedorainfracloud.org/coprs/ncarboni/pglogical-SCL/repo/epel-7/ncarboni-pglogical-SCL-epel-7.repo
---> Running in 9bca2fce10d7
Cannot start container 9bca2fce10d74375a70250a4ab4c6d3d38cdf510c943e90cab4235400f1b053a: [9] System error: exit status 1
```

What I am not 100% sure about is whether I should run it with sudo or without. I tried without and I got:

```
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this host?
```

Which is weird because I know that the service indeed runs:

```
$ sudo service docker status
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl status docker.service
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
Active: active (running) since Thu 2016-08-04 16:13:37 IDT; 12min ago
Docs: http://docs.docker.com
Main PID: 3460 (sh)
CGroup: /system.slice/docker.service
├─3460 /bin/sh -c /usr/bin/docker-current daemon --authorization-plugin=rhel-push-plugin --exec-opt native.cgro...
├─3462 /usr/bin/docker-current daemon --authorization-plugin=rhel-push-plugin --exec-opt native.cgroupdriver=systemd --selinux-enable...
└─3463 /usr/bin/forward-journald -tag docker
```

Any pointers to what should I do here?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your users to the docker group to be able to use docker from a user that is not root.

If you want to use the docker container with a socket under 1024 you will have to be in dockerroot too.

https://forums.docker.com/t/unable-to-use-docker-without-sudo/8982/2